# Prevent kubuntu from remembering previous session

Tags: kubuntu, kde

If I shutdown pc while, for example, a konsole is opened, at the next boot kubuntu will load that konsole. This happens for each file/program opened.

I don't want this.
Is there a way to prevent it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

KDE System Settings > Startup and Shutdown > Desktop Session > On Login

[image: Screenshot]

**Documents**

KDE Help Center - Session Management

> On Login You may choose one of three options on what should happen
> when you log into KDE:
>
> Restore previous session If this option is
> checked, KDE will save your current session's state when you logout.
> KDE will restore your session on the next login, so you can continue
> to work with a desktop just like you left it.
>
> Restore manually saved
> session Instead of restoring KDE to the state it was when you logged
> out last, it will be restored to a specific state that you have saved
> manually. If this option is checked, the start menu offers an
> additional item Leave → Save Session.
>
> Start with an empty session If
> you choose this option, KDE will never restore sessions that it has
> saved.

(Old older versions of KDE, you can find this setting at: KDE System Settings > Startup and Shutdown > Session Management > On Login)

KDE UserBase System Settings/Startup and Shutdown : http://userbase.kde.org/System_Settings/Startup_and_Shutdown