# Ubuntu does not restore user state on power up

Tags: restore

When Ubuntu is powered up; it does not restore the open windows and applications that were running at shutdown.  Since Ubuntu 18.04 hangs up frequently, it is necessary to power off and on to get the computer working again. The CentOS and Fedora systems restore the user's open applications on power up; Ubuntu should do that also.

How can I set Ubuntu to do so?

efr

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a setting in the startup applications menu item to remember all apps when shutting down?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1021413/is-there-a-setting-in-the-startup-applications-menu-item-to-remember-all-apps-wh)

Answer (score 1):

Regular Ubuntu doesn't restore the previous session but if this is an important feature you can switch to `kubuntu`. This [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/428805/prevent-kubuntu-from-remembering-previous-session) has a sample screen I've recycled to display the setup:

[image]

---

You can configure regular Ubuntu to automatically startup your favourite applications but they will not continue where they left off. There are a few exceptions such as web browsers which continue where they left of.

Use the **Startup Applications** app to define which applications automatically load when you sign on:

[image: Startup Applications.png]

Answer (score 0):

As a compliment to [@WinEunuuchs2Unix](https://askubuntu.com/a/1083556/66509) answer I can recommend to switch to [MATE Desktop Environment](http://mate-desktop.org/).
It have classic look & feel with session restore functionality.

You can enable it from *System→Preferences→Personal→Startup Applications* (or `mate-session-properties`) on *Options* tab, it is named *Automatically remember running applications when logging out*:

[image: Ubuntu MATE 18.04 LTS has Session Restore functionality]

From my personal experience it restore several GTK-based applications such as MATE Terminal, Firefox, Pluma, Atril, Caja, Zotero, SeaMonkey on next boot.