# Having my applications open on startup

Tags: ubuntu-mate

Hello I am running Ubuntu Mate and what is anoying is when I have all my apps open and power off at the end of the day. The next mornining I have a blank screen and have to open up all the apps I use for the day. Is their a way to have that apps I want to use open when I power on?

Comment: You've tagged you're running Lubuntu (ie. LXQt desktop) but say you're running Ubuntu-MATE.  Please provide OS & release details as what you've provided contradicts (MATE is a GTK3 desktop, LXQt used by Lubuntu is a Qt5 desktop, and what you're asking about is desktop related)

Comment: Check https://askubuntu.com/a/1083619/66509 .

Answer (score 0):

Click on the grid to open applications; at the top (in the search bar), enter 'startup' and click on the suggested 'startup applications'. You can then add the programs you want to open when you start up.